# vivisect get assembly instructions

Tags: disassembly

I was going through Vivisect Documentation which seems limited. I wanted to create a tool that gets the functions and then get the assembly code or just assembly instruction (mnemonics ) in a given function. Any help will be valuable.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

:>type vivtest.py

```
import vivisect
import envi.common as ec
vw = vivisect.VivWorkspace()
vw.loadFromFile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Debuggers\\x64\\cdb.exe")
vw.analyze()
for i in vw.getFunctions():
    if ((vw.getName(i)) == "cdb.FindPESection"):
        fb = vw.getFunctionBlocks(i)
        funcstart = fb[0][0]
        res = vw.parseOpcode(funcstart)
        nextaddr = funcstart+res.size
        print(hex(funcstart) ,end =" ")
        print("%-15s" % (ec.hexify(vw.readMemory(funcstart,res.size))),end = " ")
        print(res)
        while (nextaddr < (funcstart + fb[0][1])):
            res = vw.parseOpcode(nextaddr)
            print(hex(nextaddr) ,end =" ")
            print("%-15s" % (ec.hexify(vw.readMemory(nextaddr,res.size))),end = " ")
            print(res)
            nextaddr = nextaddr+res.size
```

:>python vivtest.py

```
0x14000cdc0 4c63413c        movsxd r8,dword [rcx + 60]
0x14000cdc4 4533c9          xor r9d,r9d
0x14000cdc7 4c03c1          add r8,rcx
0x14000cdca 4c8bd2          mov r10,rdx
0x14000cdcd 410fb74014      movzx eax,word [r8 + 20]
0x14000cdd2 450fb75806      movzx r11d,word [r8 + 6]
0x14000cdd7 4883c018        add rax,24
0x14000cddb 4903c0          add rax,r8
0x14000cdde 4585db          test r11d,r11d
0x14000cde1 741e            jz 0x14000ce01
```

confirmation using windbg

```
0:000> u cdb!FindPESection l0xa
cdb!FindPESection:
00007ff6`9280cdc0 4c63413c        movsxd  r8,dword ptr [rcx+3Ch]
00007ff6`9280cdc4 4533c9          xor     r9d,r9d
00007ff6`9280cdc7 4c03c1          add     r8,rcx
00007ff6`9280cdca 4c8bd2          mov     r10,rdx
00007ff6`9280cdcd 410fb74014      movzx   eax,word ptr [r8+14h]
00007ff6`9280cdd2 450fb75806      movzx   r11d,word ptr [r8+6]
00007ff6`9280cdd7 4883c018        add     rax,18h
00007ff6`9280cddb 4903c0          add     rax,r8
00007ff6`9280cdde 4585db          test    r11d,r11d
00007ff6`9280cde1 741e            je      cdb!FindPESection+0x41 (00007ff6`9280ce01)
```